# Scale a UIImage appropriately to show it fullscreen without any distortions

Tags: iphone, uiimage

When we take a photo on an iphone , the image is shown in fullscreen without any "grey bar" at the top i.e. the image is shown in the frame 320*500 size . I want to display that image in my app , but the app has a maximum frame of size 320*480 . Hence when I try to show the image in my app as fullscreen , it is shown as a stretched image . I tried  all `contentMode` options but it didn't work .
So , how to scale an image or how to fix a size of frame so that the image is shown as it is but in a smaller frame without any distortions or something like in "Photos" app of iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take a picture, you actually don't see the full-sized photo, you see only the part which fits your display instead (the photo's resolution is bigger than the iPhone's display resolution). So if you want to take a resulting image and show it fullscreen, then you need to do some simple calculations in order to scale image, leaving its proportions correct:

```
// We know the desired resolution. It's full screen (320, 480) or (640, 960).
// Now we want to determine the destination imageView frame with maximum dimensions
// for it to fit the screen AND leave the image's proportions
float minScale = MIN(screenResolution.width/actualImgWidth, screenResolution.height/actualImgHeight);
// With minScale one side will fit full screen, and the other will occupy a bit smaller space than the screen allows
destImgView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, minScale*actualImgWidth, minScale*actualImgHeight);
destImgView.image = actualImg;
```